# How to create a circle and a bar that overlap with css?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

For a user profile I'm trying to create a circular image plus a horizontal bar with the same height as the image. Also, it should be responsive. It should look as in the image below. In the black bar there will be text.

[image]

*Could someone please help me with the correct CSS?* 
So far I have the code below but this already goes wrong in that the black bar is below the circle and not next to it. But also I don't know how to make the black bar start exactly in the middle of the image, to have the image on top, and to have text in the black bar start sufficiently to the right (while being responsive to screen size).

```
<div class="col-md-12 profile-topbar">
  <div class="round">
    <img src=<%= image_path('profile.gif') %>>
  </div>
  <div class="text-bar">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS file:

```
.round {
  margin: 2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
.round img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-bar {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #FFF;
  left: 222px; //Problem: not responsive. This block should start exactly halfway from the image.
  width: 100%;
}
.text-bar p {
  left: 250 px;
}
```

Comment: so a 'switch' button but without the function / action?

Comment: so, css3 rounded cornered divs overlapping? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could use `figure` and `figcaption` to structure your html.

`Inline-block`, `vertical-align` and `margin` to set image aside text

```css
figure {
  margin-left:50px;/* half image width */
  background:black;
  box-shadow:0 0 1px;
  border-radius:3px;
  }
img {
  border-radius:100%;
  position:relative;/* brings it at front, can trigger z-index too */
  box-shadow:-1px 0 1px, 1px 0 1px white ;/* whatever U like */
  vertical-align:middle;
  right:50px;/* move visually from real position */
  margin-right:-40px;/* pull or push text aside */
  }
figcaption {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  color:white;
  }
p {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9" />
  <figcaption>
    <p>some text here  10px away from image</p>
    <p>and more</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

Comment: Thanks, got it to work! I was wondering what the '/' is for at the end of the line `<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9" />`?

Comment: it a self closing element , like br , hr , input. you do not add it when doctype used is html 4.01 ( capital are then used too) , when you do html5 it is optionnal but most of the time html coding is more like xhtml rules , more strict , it's a matter of practice mainly.

Comment: I added a follow-up question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30949052/positioning-of-divs-using-css-layout-issue-with-absolute-positioned-div

Answer (score 4):

The idea is - (1) set `margin-left:50px` on the container, and `margin-left:-50px` on the avatar inside. (2) set the bio as a table, so we can use the vertical alignment feature to middle the text.

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aLrpd8zw/)**</kbd>

```css
body {
    background: silver;
}
.user {
    height: 100px;
    background: #222;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.avatar {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    margin-left: -50px;
}
.bio {
    display: table;
    height: 100px;
    color: #fff;
}
.bio p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="user">
    <img class="avatar" src="http://i.imgur.com/9pnkFjf.jpg" />
    <div class="bio"><p>John Doe is an anonymous character.</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved already various issues. Two problems left: 1) text in the bar is placed below the bar instead of inside it, even though I have: `<div class="bar">` `<div class="round">` `</div>` `<p>Text</p>` `</div>`. 2) Even though the width of the bar is set to 100%, it is wider than the `div` the bar is placed in (wider than `<div class="col-md-12 profile-topbar">`. Any ideas how to solve these two issues?

Comment: @Nick the text thing is easy to fix - http://jsfiddle.net/rb10ghnu/1/ not sure what you mean by the width issue.

Comment: @Nick I figured out the width thing - you can just remove `width:100%` from the bar, because div is block level, it will take the entire width of the container without set any width, like what i did on the demo. Or set it to `width:auto` if you need to reset it.

Comment: Thanks Pangloss, it worked if I literally used your code but if I adjusted it for my situation I couldn't get it to work. But GCyrillus his answer did. (no doubt that it's my implementation that is the problem, and not your code.)

Comment: @Nick no problems, I took a look the only main difference is it's set with relative position + negative left value, anyway must be something going on with your code, otherwise they should work the same way. By the way the `/` is the xhtml thing, you don't have to use it with html5.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to absolutely position the title bar.

http://codepen.io/fontophilic/pen/LVzbVM?editors=110

I'm using SCSS in my pen, but here is the compiled css:

```
.round {
  margin: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.round img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-bar {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  left: 75px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.text-bar p {
  position: relative;
  left: 75px;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="circle">
</div>


html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }
.circle{
 border-radius:50%;
 width:3em;
 height:3em;
 background-color: red;
 }
.circle:before{
margin-left: 1.5em;
content: " ";
display: block;
position: relative;
background: black;
height: 3em;
width: 500%;
z-index:-1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/yNzVJz