# Positioning of div's using css: layout issue with absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

The code below shows a circle plus a bar, built using a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925853/how-to-create-a-circle-and-a-bar-that-overlap-with-css). The problem I'm experiencing is that the `bar` in practice has a fixed height equal to the `circle`'s height. I guess this is because of the `absolute` `inline-block`. However, I seem to need `absolute` `inline-block` because without them `text` is placed below the bar instead of inside it.

The problem I'm experiencing is that if the text within the `text` div does not fit within `bar` (too much text), the text runs belows the bar (so the heigth of the bar is not expanding). Second problem is that if there's very little text within `bar`, the `bottom-half` overlaps with `bar`. How can I adjust my code for these problems?

```css
.tophalf {
  width: 100%;
  background: #F1F3F2 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  padding: 5em;
}
.bar {
  background: #333;
  margin-left: 75px;
  min-height: 150px;
}
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin-left: -75px;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="tophalf">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="bar">
        <div class="circle"></div>
        <div class="text">My text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom-half"></div>
```

*In the code snippet the text "My text" shows up below the bar, while it shows up inside bar in my app. I don't know the cause. Perhaps it is because of the container `div` from bootstrap, which the snippet doesn't perhaps process as such.*

Comment: The text does the funk under the bar because of the "position:absolute" property. Looking at the rest, but don't really get your question .. EDIT: well, bar seems to be increasing in height. The overlap problem is no where to be found. But i may not understand fully what you want to do. Does https://fiddle.jshell.net/mnocmL7r/ look right? Or do you want it to look like in your previous post?

Comment: Yeah, I can't get the snippet to look the way it does on the development server. I don't understand it. Text should be located inside the bar (to begin with)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser is not able to adjust the height of the 'bar' because you are defining a location for the 'text' using 'absolute'. Can you please update the css style using the below one and see if it helps?

```css
.circle {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;`
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  margin-left: -75px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
  margin-top: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the text-div position is absolute, it will not affect the height of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you need an element to size its height based on its content, then you can either set it to be `display: block` or set `height: auto`.